# Pass parameters to RelayCommand in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I know that there are multiple posts with similar titles all over SOF and Google, but please bear with me for a minute.

I am following this article to create a context menu for my gridview: http://www.koaxkoaxkoax.com/ribbit/2010/09/creating-dynamic-menus-in-wpf.html

I create the HierarchicalDataTemplate in `UserControl.Resources`, I have an empty menu in the resources of the gridview, which I then reference in the actual context menu. The XAML (first part of the gridview) looks like this:

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Views:ViewMenuItemCollection x:Key="Menu">
                <Views:ViewMenuItem Text="foo"/>
                <Views:ViewMenuItem Text="bar"/>
            </Views:ViewMenuItemCollection>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Menu}"/>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

In the code behind I use `FindResource` to get a reference to the menu and create one `ViewMenuItem`-object that is on the same level as `foo` and `bar`. Then I iterate through a list and create one `ViewMenuItem`-object per list item and attach them as child objects. That looks just as I want to have it. But I can't get the actual functionality to work.

The inner part of the foreach-loop (where I create the child objects) looks like this:

```
ViewMenuItem seriesItem = new ViewMenuItem();
seriesItem.Text = series.ForcedName;
seriesItem.Command = new RelayCommand<Series>(p=>_view.SetSeriesExecute(p));             
_setSeriesMenuItem.Children.Add(seriesItem);
```

Especially the line containing `p=>_view.SetSeriesExecute(p)` is confusing me. I have found many many examples that look exactly like it. When I run my program and click on one of the child elements, the `SetSeriesExecute` method is properly called - but the paramter is always null. Not too surprising, because at no point I actually supply an object of type `Series` as parameter. I have tried to provide the parameter in the RelayCommand constructor like this: `p=>_view.SetSeriesExecute(mySeriesObject)`. It compiles, but `SetSeriesExecute` is never called.

My goal is very simple (at least I think it is): When the program reacts to a click on an element in the context menu, the method (`SetSeriesExecute`) needs to know which item has actually been selected (=clicked on) by the user. Unfortunately I was not able to figure out where and how I can supply the parameters to `SetSeriesExecute`, despite 4 hours of serious research. And the fact that everyone else seems to understand the available examples doesn't make me feel particularly good about myself and I offer lifelong gratitude for every hint.

Best
Peter

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the `CommandParameter`.

Try setting `seriesItem.CommandParameter` to whatever you would like to pass to the `SetSeriesExecute` method.  `p` in `p=>_view.SetSeriesExecute(mySeriesObject)` will be that parameter.

Comment: +1, or apply a binding to the `CommandParameter`. In fact, both should be bound.

Comment: I have added `Series CommandParameter` to my `ViewMenuItem`-class. But the parameter in `SetSeriesExecute` is still null. How would SetSeriesExecute know to look for this Property anyway?

Comment: What is `series.ForcedName` ?

Comment: `ForcedName` is a string property and is used as the text of the menu item

Comment: I thought text is set here: `<Views:ViewMenuItem Text="foo"/>`

Comment: Yes, those are different items. In my example I create 2 items in XAML and one item with many child items at runtime. My question is how I can pass parameters at runtime without XAML databinding.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Can you give me a short example of what I have to do?